# What logo would you like for the site?

Tags: discussion, design

Ok, it's a new site and it's beta and everything...

But it's fun to think about these things too, isn't it?

**Do you have proposal on an image for a site's logo?**

(A little explanation would be nice too)

Answer (score 5):

Sure I have an image myself:

[image]

It is fairly easy and with high to recognition value. It has like everything to do with AI and is a discussion topic for [every party](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hal+9000+costume&t=canonical&iax=1&ia=images) :)

Comment: This is the scientifically correct answer, all other answers are void.